# Git head via post-update

Tags: git, githooks, git-reset, post-update

I have a local dev server where I do all my changes, we'll call this `local`.
I have a git repo setup in a git folder on my `webserver`, we'll call this `gitfolder`.
And then I have my live files, that are being pushed from gitfolder everytime I git push, we'll call this `live`.

My workflow.

Edit files, commit changes, push to `webserver`.  Then a post-update takes over with the following:

```
#!/bin/sh
export GIT_WORK_TREE=/path/to/live
git checkout -f
```

This works perfectly.  However, here lies my question.  I want to revert a git change, and I would normally do this via `git reset --hard commit` - but I if I navigate to `live`, obviously that's not a git repo.

When I go over to `gitfolder` and run the same command `git reset --hard commit` it doesn't update `live` and I get the error 'fatal: This operation must be run in a work tree'

Steps to take?  For now, I've gone and copied my `local` folder and made a `local2` - and on `local2` I reverted the change, then pushed that to `live`, so my original `local` folder still has all the changes.

I DO NOT WANT TO REVERT `local`- Just on `live`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You probably don't want to change any refs in the server either (`git reset` would move whatever branch `HEAD` points to, probably `master`, but you said you don't want to revert or reset your local system, so based on that, I assume you don't want to revert or reset your bare repository either).

In that case, just log on to the server, `cd` to the bare repository, and run:

```
git checkout --work-tree=/path/to/live checkout -f <commit-ID>
```

or:

```
GIT_WORK_TREE=/path/to/live git checkout -f <commit-ID>
```

In other words, you're just doing what the update hook does, but with a raw commit-ID to extract that particular version, without changing any branches in the repository itself.

---

While I think that's the literal answer to your question, I'd like to point out something else: if you `git revert` the bad commit in your own local repository, you get a new commit that undoes the effect of the bad commit, but the bad commit *is still in there*.  You can then push the result to the server, in the usual way:

```
... - o - X - o - U   <-- master, origin/master
```

where `X` is the bad commit and `U` is the commit that "un-does" what `X` does.  Just for illustration I've included an uninteresting `o` commit in between them, too.

Now you can simply revert your revert, so that your local repo ends with the "bad" commit being replayed yet again:

```
... - o - X - o - U       <-- origin/master
                    \
                      X'  <-- master
```

where `X'` is a copy of the bad commit, which "un-does" the undoing that `U` did.  You can now fix it up, make another commit on top or `git commit --amend`, etc., and when it all works, `git push` the result to the server again.  That would be a more typical way to deal with the issue.

---

Based on comments, here is another option, which may or may not be suitable, better, etc: instead of resetting or reverting locally, make a new local branch or tag (let's use branch here) that points to the commit you want restored on the server.  You may also want a name on the server, so that it won't garbage-collect commits (which would mean you would have to send them over the network again later).

For instance, let's say the tree on `local` looks like this, drawn with a kink just so that I can add a label:

```
... - o - R
            \
              X - o - o -...- o   <-- HEAD=master, origin/master
```

Here `R` is the commit you want the server to reset-to, while `X` and the additional commits are the ones that update Wordpress plug-ins and so on.  (I'm assuming you're working on branch `master`; change as needed.)

Meanwhile, over on the server, things look like this:

```
... - o - R
            \
              X - o - o -...- o   <-- HEAD=master
```

If you want to retain all the commits on the server, we should give the final `o` commit a new branch-name, since we'll have to force-update `master` there.  So on `local`, we might run this:

```
$ git push origin master:save
```

This will create a new branch on the server, called `save`, so that it now looks like this:

```
... - o - R
            \
              X - o - o -...- o   <-- HEAD=master, save
```

The `update` hook will do the usual `git checkout -f`, which checks out the `HEAD` branch (since no branch is specified), which in this case is `master`, so the server is updated to the last `o` commit (pointlessly, it's already there).  But next, we do this, again on `local`:

```
$ git branch for-server <commit-ID-for-R>
```

This changes the setup on `local` to look like this:

```
... - o - R                       <-- for-server
            \
              X - o - o -...- o   <-- HEAD=master, origin/master
```

Not very interesting yet, but next:

```
$ git push --force origin for-server:master
```

This (with `--force`) tells the server to forcibly update its `master` to point to commit `R`, after which it has this:

```
... - o - R                       <-- HEAD=master
            \
              X - o - o -...- o   <-- save
```

That `save` label keeps the remaining commits in the repository on the server.  Meanwhile the `post-update` hook runs and does a `git checkout -f`, which uses `HEAD`, which points to `master`, which points to commit `R`.  So the web server should now have commit `R` deployed.

Back on `local`, you just need to remember that `for-server` maps to `master` on the remote.  (If you like, you can rename all your local branches to match the naming on the server: change `master` to `save` and change `for-server` to `master`, for instance.  That's all independent of this.)

Note that the only thing `save` is doing on the server is keeping commits `X` and all the subsequent `o`s.  That's nice if you want to work on the server directly, or don't want to send those commits back over the net.  However, if, on the server (which has a work-directory since it's not a bare repo), you a `git checkout save`, you'll change `HEAD` to point to `save` and the next time the `post-update` hook runs, it will deploy the `save` version, rather than the `master` version.

Comment: I don't have a bare repository.  On the server I have the git directory, with a remote setup to look like this: `un@domain.tld:~/home/git/project.git`  When I navigate to `project.git` and run your command, I get the error: `fatal: this operation must be run in a work tree`

Comment: Ah, well, this will all work with a non-bare repo as well (though you run into all the usual issues with updating the current branch, vs someone working in the non-bare repo).  The error is a bit puzzling: with `--work-tree=` or `GIT_WORK_TREE=` you're forcing git to use the other path as the work tree.  That path must exist, else the update hook wouldn't work.

Comment: Thank you for your edit on the fixing of a bad commit.  For me, this isn't the case though.  I updated quite a few Wordpress plugins, pushed them to the server, then realized that they aren't compatible.  I can't un-update them, and I've done quite a few commits since then.  So I was trying to revert back to the commit before I did any of the updates, fix the server issues, then go back to the most recent commit.

Comment: Ah, OK, in that case the idea of just extracting an old one makes sense.  I guess the next question is, does pushing run as some other user ID that has different permissions to write on the live tree?

Comment: Your save branch was an excellent idea, and I can see where that would work.  I marked your answer as the correct answer, as my solution seemed a bit hacky.  What I did was make a backup of the `local` directory first, then reset hard to pre-update commit.  Pushed that to the server.  I then fixed the changes, and was able to find the commit id by going into the backup, using git log, copying the commit #, and going back into `local` and git reset to that id.  Worked for me.  But it could have gone bad.